# Appending list as an object to an existing list

Tags: python

I've been stuck with a problem for a few days now and I can't come up with a solution. I have a code where a function accepts a string of operators and operands and returns a list of them. The function is designed to look for parantheses, and in case it finds them, it recalls itself with the string inside the parantheses and appends it as a list to a previously created empty list. For an example, if i send in a string "= int int", the return list would be ["=", "int", "int"]. If I send in a string "+ (+ int int) int" the return list would be ["+", ["+", "int", "int"], "int"].

However, the problem arises when a string in the form of "= (+ int int)(+ int int)", is sent in, meaning a string with two parantheses one after another. The returning list becomes
["=", ["+", "int", "int", ["+", "int", "int"]]], but the wanted result should be:
["=", ["+", "int", "int"], ["+", "int", "int"]]. The code is listed below, and I really need some help in figuring what's wrong with it.

```
def convert(string):
string=" "+string
lst = []
i = 0
while i < len(string):
    if string[i] == "(":
        p = 0 #keeps track of parantheses
        i2 = 0
        for i2 in range(len(string[i+1:])):
            if i2 == ")" and p == 0:
                break
            elif i2 == "(":
                p += 1
            elif i2 == ")" and p > 0:
                p -= 1
        lst += [convert(string[i+1:i+1+i2+1])]
        i += i2
    if string[i] == " " and string[i+1] != "(":
        try:
            lst += [getWord(string[i::])]
        except:
            pass
    i += 1
return lst
```

I'd really appreciate your help, thanks!

EDIT: The function also uses another function which returns a word.

```
def getWord(string):
word = string.split()[0]
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i] == ')':
        word = word[0:i]
        break
return word
```

Testrun:

```
>>> convert("> (+ int int)(quotient real real)")
['>', ['+', 'int', 'int', ['quotient', 'real', 'real']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One issue you had was you set `i2` to loop through a `range()` and then tried to compare `i2` to a string. (Example: `if i2 == ")"`).

**This code is tested and will work:**

```
def convert(string):
    string=" "+string
    lst = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(string)-1:
        if string[i] == "(":
            p = 0 #keeps track of parantheses
            i2 = 0
            for i2 in range(i+1, len(string)):
                if string[i2] == ")" and p == 0:
                    break
                elif string[i2] == "(":
                    p += 1
                elif string[i2] == ")" and p > 0:
                    p -= 1
            lst += [convert(string[i+1:i2])]
            i = i2
        if string[i] == " " and string[i+1] != "(":
            try:
                lst += [getWord(string[i::])]
            except:
                pass
        i += 1
    return lst
```

Here is my test run:

```
>>> convert("> (+ int int)(quotient real real)")
['>', ['+', 'int', 'int'], ['quotient', 'real', 'real']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This functions (no getWord() function required):

```
def convert(string):
    rc = []
    cstr = ''
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(string):
        if string[idx] == '(':
            rc.append(convert(string[idx+1:]))
            inc = string[idx+1:].find(')')
            if inc >= 0:
                idx += (inc + 1)
        elif string[idx] == ')':
            if len(cstr):
                rc.append(cstr)
                cstr = ''
            return rc
        elif string[idx] == ' ':
            if len(cstr):
                rc.append(cstr)
                cstr = ''
        else:
            cstr += string[idx]
        idx += 1
    if len(cstr):
        rc.append(cstr)
    return rc
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, for a problem like this one should use a parser library. I like [Parcon](http://blog.parcon.opengroove.org/).

Why then, you ask, should one use a Parser Library? Because it is easier to reason about code that lives on a higher level of abstraction. While [cforbish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20302640/395321) solved the problem you had perfectly, he didn't remedy the other flaws in your code. Take for example these lines:

```
print convert('+ (- int int) (* (/ hey ho) bar')
print convert('+ (- int int) (* (/ hey ho huh))')
print convert('+ (- int int) (* (/ + -))')
```

Result:

```
['+', ['-', 'int', 'int'], ['*', ['/', 'hey', 'ho'], 'ba']]
['+', ['-', 'int', 'int'], ['*', ['/', 'hey', 'ho', 'huh']]]
['+', ['-', 'int', 'int'], ['*', ['/', '+', '-']]]
```

In the first line it erroneously steals the last character of *bar*, because of a missing closing parenthesis. In the second line it accepts a third operand for a binary operator. And in the third line it accepts operators as operands. What is the result of dividing plus by minus?

Here's a better (and much shorter) solution:

```
from parcon import Forward, Word, alphanum_chars

Expr = Forward()
Operand = Word(alphanum_chars) | '(' + Expr + ')'
Operator = Word(alphanum_chars) | Word('+-*/<>', max=1)
Expr << (Operator + Operand + Operand)[list]

def convert(s):
    return Expr.parse_string(s)

print convert('+ (- int int) (* (/ hey ho) bar)')
```

Result:

```
['+', ['-', 'int', 'int'], ['*', ['/', 'hey', 'ho'], 'bar']]
```

The buggy input strings above produce errors, e.g.:

```
print convert('+ (- int int) (* (/ + -))')
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convstr.py", line 80, in <module>
    print convert('+ (- int int) (* (/ + -))')
  File "convstr.py", line 42, in convert
    return Expr.parse_string(s)
  File "C:\Programme\Python\2.7.2\lib\site-packages\parcon\__init__.py", line 645, in parse_string
    raise ParseException("Parse failure: " + format_failure(result.expected), result.expected)
parcon.ParseException: Parse failure: At position 20: expected one of any char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", "("
```

The code is easy enough to understand:

```
Expr = Forward()
```

This means: I'm going to use Expr, but what it actually is I'll define later.

```
Operand = Word(alphanum_chars) | '(' + Expr + ')'
```

An Operand is either a word containing only alphanumerical characters or it's an Expr enclosed in Parens.

```
Operator = Word(alphanum_chars) | Word('+-*/<>', max=1)
```

An Operator is either a word containing only alphanumerical characters or it's a word consisting of a single character out of +, -, * , /, <, >.

```
Expr << (Operator + Operand + Operand)[list]
```

Here we finally define what an Expr is: an operator followed by two operands. The `[list]` tells parcon that each such triple should be wrapped in a list. Otherwise, all parsed tokens would be put in one long flat sequence like this:

```
('+', '-', 'int', 'int', '*', '/', 'hey', 'ho', 'bar')
```